# Insomnia - CSRF cookie not set

Tags: django, insomnia

I am trying to use insomnia for POST requests for testing my API in a Django application.

I am getting this CSRF token error. I saw this post here [Django CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846186/django-csrf-failed-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect)

which tells me that I need to set my CSRF Token in my headers but I get this new error in return under Live Preview "No cookies in store for URL".

Does anyone know a workaround to this problem?