# How to use insomnia with django?

Tags: django, csrf, insomnia

running django locally and with firefox, i login with `http://localhost:8000/admin/` and after that i can access `http://localhost:8000/myCustomApi` successfully.

on insomnia every time i login with `http://localhost:8000/admin/` i get `{"code": "csrf", "reason": "CSRF cookie not set."}` on the response. i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55890179/3026886) but didn't work. is there any tutorial to what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install this plugin: https://insomnia.rest/plugins/insomnia-plugin-default-headers
2. Click on your environment and then on "Manage Environments"
   [image]

3. In your environment, add a new env var:

```
{
"DEFAULT_HEADERS": {
    "X-CSRFToken": "wSYUpsSIkXxjA8wBiojsCU7YgJGYySGFWiDHNoGhEpCWGxoIyNfIvw7hr2Au1a9J"
}
```

}

Replace the value with one you can find in your browser.

4. Now, that was for sending data to forms. If you need to make a request while being loggued, click on Cookies and add a new cookie with a name sessionid and the value that you will find in your browser.
5. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `X-CSRFToken` didn't worked for me.

So I tried to "copy" the same request in the Insomnia environment.

In my case, what I did was:

1. Go to your Browser and do at least one successful request.
2. Go to `Network` tab and copy the `Request Header` with name `Cookie`.
3. Go to Insomnia and set this same header with it values.
4. Try debbugging from Insomnia.

[image]

Insomnia:

[image]

But if something seems different to you, just keep the same core: copy the request environment from browser to insomnia.

Remember the server can't see difference between an Insomnia client and the Browser if all the headers are the same.